# Javascript to open new window in the same tab

Tags: javascript, html, tabs

```
var Index;    
var WeekTable=document.getElementbyId('MapList')    
var w = window.open("");
```

---

The code above will open a new tab and then run this code:

```
w.document.writeln('HTML CODE GOES IN HERE FOR THE NEW PAGE');
```

I want to open this page in the same tab so the user can go back to that they were currently at.

Comment: Do you mean open a new tab in the same window? So you want `window.open` to force open a new tab instead of window?

Comment: So, you want to redirect them to a new page?

Comment: window.open will open a new tab. I want to do the same thing but keep the user in the same tab so they can go back to the previous page

Answer (score 3):

... This seems weirdly trivial, but if you just want to redirect the user to a new page in the same tab, get rid of all your JavaScript and use a plain old `<a>` tag, where the `href` is set to the URL you want to go to. What you're describing is exactly the behaviour you get from a dead simple link, so I'm not sure why you don't just use one:

```
<a href="/mypage.html">Click Here</a>
```

If you have to run some JavaScript first, bind to the link's `click` event, and then *don't* return false or run `event.preventDefault()` inside your event handler, and the link will still be followed by the browser after your event handler is done.

If you *must* to do the actual "redirection" in JavaScript for some reason, assign the URL to `window.location` instead of using `window.open`:

```
window.location = "http://mysite.com/mypage.html"
```

Comment: if I use <a href="/mypage.html">Click Here</a> then I will not be able to access my HTML table that currently holds JavaScript data. If there is a way to do that then I would be happy to know. Im very new to JavaScript and HTML. I currently load an HTML table then javascript edits that table onclick. Then I take the current data in the HTML table('MapList') and grab the information I want from that table and display it using the w.open(""); w.document.writeline...etc

Comment: This is the only way I know how to take my current data to a new page

Comment: As I said in my answer, use `window.location = ...` instead of `window.open(...)`.

Comment: If I use window.location = "" then it takes me to the default index.php file

Comment: if I create a new.php file for that code then say window.location="Http://mysite.com/new.php" then I dont understand how I can carry javascript variables over to that new.php page.

Comment: Use the query string; `window.location = "/mypage.php?x=3&y=4"`.

Comment: ok and then in my new.php file how will I access lets say the x and y variables?

Comment: or how can I display those x and y variables from my javascript into a table in my new page?

Comment: does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding,since you want to carry the data from the previous page to the new page,it could be a good idea to store the required variables in a Javascript data structure that you can access later when the new page is loaded.
You can create an array and push the data into it,and when you load the new page you will be able to access the required data.